# container of polymorphic objects - call (so to say static) function once per containing class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a virtual base `class B` and some deriving classes `class D1`, `class D2`, `class D3`.
I also have a container holding pointer to number of instances `Container<B*> cont;`

Now i have some different type of tasks:

- things that need to be done for each object (thats the classic - no problems with that)
- things that need to be done once for each kind of object (that also does not depend on the object itself)

To make it more imaginable a bit of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class B{
public:
  virtual void executeOncePerClass() = 0;
  virtual void executeOncePerObject() = 0;
};
using Container = std::vector<B*>;

class D1 : public B 
{ 
public:
  D1(int i_i):i(i_i){}
  void executeOncePerClass() override { executeOncePerClass_s(); };
  void executeOncePerObject()override { std::cout << " D1 : " << i << " member " << std::endl;};
private:
  int i = 0;
  static void executeOncePerClass_s(){ std::cout << " D1  static" << std::endl; };
};

class D2 : public B 
{ 
/* same as D1 */
public:
  D2(int i_i):i(i_i){}
  void executeOncePerClass() override { executeOncePerClass_s(); };
  void executeOncePerObject()override { std::cout << " D2 : " << i << " member " << std::endl;};
private:
  int i = 0;
  static void executeOncePerClass_s(){ std::cout << " D2  static" << std::endl; };
};

class D3 : public B 
{ 
public:
  D3(float i_i):i(i_i){}
  void executeOncePerClass() override { executeOncePerClass_s(); };
  void executeOncePerObject()override { std::cout << " D3 : " << i << " member " << std::endl;};
private:
  float i = 0;
  static void executeOncePerClass_s(){ std::cout << " D3  static" << std::endl; };
};

int main(){
  D1 d1_1(1); D1 d1_2(2); D1 d1_3(3);
  D2 d2_1(23);
  D3 d3_1(1); D3 d3_2(2); D3 d3_3(3);

  Container cont{ 
     &d3_2, &d1_1, &d3_3, /* &d2_1 */ &d3_1, &d1_3, &d1_2
  };

  std::cout << " foreach class " << std::endl;
  for(auto c : cont){
    /* ??? */
  }

  std::cout << " foreach instance: " << std::endl;
  for(auto c : cont){
    c->executeOncePerObject();
  }

}
```

Is there some easy code to get this done? 
Maybe storing the `executeOncePerClass` functions address (this would also capture the if D4 inherits from D3 without overriding)?
At best without a lot of dynamic memory or associative container?

One Sidequestion: is there a better mechanism for this polymorphic static function thingy?

Comment: How close is the example to the real use? If the `Container` is just going to be populated then run over like the example, running a filter on the container itself, and only calling `executeOncePerObject` on each of the first unique instances would probably be cleaner.

Comment: on one hand you use container with pointers to base class, which imply you want to treat each object in same exact way regardless of its actual type. on other hand you want to call some method once per unique class, which implies that way you treat objects depends on the actual class. may be you should rethink your design

Comment: it is just a very compressed example. in reality the usage is in different places from creation. the container gets filled with some objects created by a factory pattern. Later regularly the output for each class and a bit later for each object is requested.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur the conrete use case is a little IoT device library controlling website creation. there are different classes of controls that may be instantiated with some configuration (linked to some kind of device hardware). Each control may setup some CSS and Javascript code, but this code is only required once per class. The (eg) Button that is placed on the website and uses the CSS and Scripts at the end of course dependend on the instance

Comment: I think if you're only calling the each object request in one place then I'd go with passing the container through a filter to get only unique classes, then iterating through the result to call the once per class method. Unless you wanted to use your existing factory to track unique classes as they're created.

Comment: I think your idea of storing function addresses in something like a std::set<> is the best option.

Comment: it seems to be forbidden to store addresses of virtual functions `error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function`.
Also my environment has RTTI disabled, which disables me to set up a set of `type_index`. The only thing i came up with is a function that returns the static function pointer